# Appropriate group by mysql query

Tags: mysql

[image]

I need to group by table data by first credit_number (O47.1 - credit number with '.1') and it's account number and sum balance_at_start and balance_at_end columns with other rows which like first credit number (O47.2, O47.3, O47.4)
At the end i must get the folowwing results:

```
| 047.1 | 10753972700000037101 | 0.02   | 0.02 |
| 047.1 | 17531972705000037101 | 0.03   | 0.03 |
| O45.1 | 10753972100000421401 | 385.05 | 486  |
| O45.1 | 17531972804000421401 | 12     | 0.00 |
| O46.1 | 10753972300000005601 | 0.02   | 0.02 |
| O46.1 | 17531972004000005601 | 229    | 0.00 |
```

Comment: How do you get 047.1 | 10753972700000037101 | 0.02   | 0.02 |

Comment: Actualy not, i want to group by two columns. There can be various number of charachters. In example i just show credit number with three charachters

Comment: does a simple group by credit_number, account_number work?